# SASS\SCSS, родительский селектор в пределах одного тега

Tags: sass, scss

Есть два селектора в одном теге, с записью через точку без пробела - .selector1.selector2

Подскажите плз., как это правильно записать со ссылкой на родительский селектор? Чтобы вместо
.navbar-catalog-top было &-top:

```
.navbar-catalog {
  &.navbar-catalog-top {
    border-radius:  0 0 $border-radius $border-radius;
    border-top: none;
  }
}
```